# How to select a particular column value from a pandas dataframe when another column in the same row is NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm pretty new to pandas, and I'm trying to do a simple operation. I'm trying to make some comparisons and pick some values from a column when a condition is met. But I don't know how to give these conditions in Pandas. It's very straightforward using lists but in dataframe it's new to me.

A code example is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Student_Subjects_Initial': ['A','B','C','D'],
                    'Student_Marks_Initial': [10,23,3,45],
                    'Student_Subjects_Final': ['A',np.nan,'C','D'],
                    'Student_Marks_Final': [10,23,3,np.nan]})
```

This will give me the below in `df`:

```
 Student_Subjects_Initial   Student_Marks_Initial   Student_Subjects_Final  Student_Marks_Final
0   A                           10                      A                       10.0
1   B                           23                      nan                     23.0
2   C                           3                       C                       3.0
3   D                           45                      D                       nan
```

What I'm trying to do is pick the value from `Student_Subjects_Initial` where `Student_Subjects_Final` is `nan`.
So, my output should simply be:

```
Mismatches_Student_Subject_Initial:
B
```

But I'm unable to get my head around writing the conditon for pandas dataframe.

Can someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
df[df.Student_Subjects_Final.isnull()].Student_Subjects_Initial.to_string(index=False)
```

or with loc

```
df.loc[df['Student_Subjects_Final'].isnull()].Student_Subjects_Initial.to_string(index=False)
```

Comment: This is called "chained indexing", and should be avoided.  Use `loc` here instead: `df.loc[df['Student_Subjects_Final'].isnull(), 'Student_Subjects_Initial']`

Comment: Though this response is in the vein of the right approach, the code is syntactically incorrect and it causes the original data to be lost.

Comment: But user3483203 is correct. In the bigger terms this should be done like df.loc[df['Student_Subjects_Final'] == 'nan']].Student_Subjects_Initial. Or just like he posted for this exact thing checking on null. Which is way faster, but won't work on other values though.

Comment: @user3483203 your command works well. Thank you very much.. But it shows more detail than I expected: `1    B
Name: Student_Subjects_Initial, dtype: object` Is there a way to escape `Name` and `dtype` details as well as the index and just print the value: `B` ??

Comment: Found it.. I just had to cast the `df` into a string: `df.to_string(index=False)` - this prints just the value without any metadata of the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

This can be simply achieved by filtering rows with the desired value.

```
df = df[df['Student_Subjects_Final'].isnull()]
print(df.Student_Marks_Initial)
```

Comment: The `not` should be omitted. And this is subject to the same deficiencies highlighted in the comments of the other response (except that this code is syntactically correct).